# The lookupNamespaceURI-Algo from the specs lead to recursion errror

Tags: javascript, dom

I implemented the `lookupNamespace` for my dom but it keeps erroring out when I lookup a non-existing namespace because the call stack is full. Pseudo code for the algo can be found in the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/namespaces-algorithms.html#lookupNamespaceURIAlgo).

The reason it calls itself recursively is, because it traverses up the dom tree while searching for the namespace and when it hits the document node, the call is relayed to the documentElement - and from there it traverses up to the document again (closing the cirle).

So am I missing something obvious or is the pseudo code wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason it would go back to `document` again.
Maybe you are missing that `documentElement` is an `Element`?

- if it has a non-null *namespace* and a *prefix* that matches `prefix` it would thus return that namespace.
- if it has an `xmlns:prefix` attribute that matches `prefix` it would then return that attribute's value.
- if `prefix` is `null` and the element has an `xmlns` attribute it would then return that attribute's value.
- if none of the previous were true, it would return `null`, since it doesn't have an ancestor Element.

Comment: `if none of the previous were true, it would return null, since it doesn't have an ancestor Element.` - guess I equaled "ancestor Element" with "parentNode". I didnt now there is any difference here (htmls parentNode is the document after all). Thank you for the clarification